# C for loop won't stop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I made a clear for loop in C that is supposed to go from 0 to 3. When I run it, it goes to infinity, it never stops. I even print the counter and it keeps on going.

```
uint32_t len1, nr;  --- making TCP client/server
len1 = 3;
for ( i =0; i < len1; i++ ) {
        printf("first array number \n");
        scanf("%hu",  &nr);
        printf("got %hu %hu %hu \n", nr, i, len1);
        nr = htonl(nr);
        send(c, &nr, sizeof(nr), 0);
    }
```

My results:

```
first array number 
1
got 1 0 3 
first array number 
2
got 2 1 3 
first array number 
3
got 3 2 3 
first array number 
4
got 4 3 3 
first array number 
5
got 5 4 3 
first array number
```

and so on... Why doesn't it stop?

Complete code:

Client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint32_t len1, nr;
    int i;
    int *l1;
    int c= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( c < 0 ) {
        printf("Error creating the socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    if ( connect(c, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0 ) {
        printf("Error connecting to the server \n");
        return 1;

    }
    printf("Length1 = \n");
    scanf("%hu", &len1);
    len1 = htonl(len1);
    send(c, &len1, sizeof(len1), 0);
    len1 = ntohl(len1);
    printf("got %hu \n", len1);
    for ( i =0; i < len1; i++ ) {
        printf("first array number \n");
        scanf("%" SCNd32,  &nr);
        printf("got %hu %hu %hu \n", nr, i, len1);
        nr = htonl(nr);
        send(c, &nr, sizeof(nr), 0);
    }

    free(l1);
    close(c);
    return 0;

}
```

Server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>        
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t th[5];
int i;

void* c_thread(void *arg) {
    int *c = (int*)arg;
    int i;
    int *l1;
    uint32_t len1, nr;

    recv(*c, &len1, sizeof(len1), MSG_WAITALL);
    len1 = ntohl(len1);
    printf("got %hu \n", len1);
    l1 = malloc(len1*sizeof(int));
    for ( i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        recv(*c, &nr, sizeof(nr), MSG_WAITALL);
        nr = ntohl(nr);
    printf("got %hu %hu \n", nr, i);    
        *(l1 + i) = nr;
    }

    close(*c);
    free(l1);

}

int main ( int argc, char *argv) {
    int yes = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if ( s < 0 ){
        printf("Error creating the socket \n");
        return 1;
    }

    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
    printf("Socket created \n");

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY;

    if ( bind(s, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))< 0) {
        printf("Error binding in the server \n");
        return 1;
    }

    listen(s,10);
    printf("Server is listening \n");
    int l =sizeof(client_addr);
    memset(&client_addr, 0 ,sizeof(client_addr));
    printf("Server is running \n");
    i = 0;
    while(1){
        int c = accept(s,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &l);
        if ( c < 0 ) {
            printf("Error connecting to the client \n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("COnnectedto the client \n");
        int*argum = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *argum=c;
        pthread_create(&th[i],NULL,c_thread, argum);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tried putting a while loop instead of for. Still not working. i wont compare with len1. It passes the condition 4 < 3. I have no idea what to do

Comment: How are all those variables defined? Please post *complete* code.

Comment: and post the exact code. Your code (based on the output) seems OK.

Comment: Are all variables really defined as `unsigned short int` as your format suggests?

Comment: Well more or less. My variables are uint32_t. What else to provide? The rest of the code is unrelated to the issue, I even commented it. Would my server affect in any way the behaviour of this for loop which is in the client?

Comment: `htonl` takes 32bit, maybe you need `htons`, `hu` takes `short int` in `scanf`

Comment: @Melye77 Provide a complete program that demonstrates the issue (and contains no unrelated code).

Comment: aa my variables are defined as uint32_t

Comment: @Melye77 Then all of your `%hu` are wrong.

Comment: I've been solving my problems with variables defined as uint32_t all the time and %hu was how I read/printed them, it worked. What else should I provide to make this question fit? I added code, desired behavior and it's the shortest code

Comment: @Melye77 you're just unlucky that it worked. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Melye77 bro, you're changing the loop condition `len1` every time the loop is looped. Your code is working exactly as you've written it to.

Comment: Ok I made a change and I printed printf("%ld, %ld", i, len1); Apparently this time, i stays 0, never gets incremented. My len1 = 3 is outside the loop. How am I changing it?

Comment: @Melye77 Neither `%ld` nor `%hu` are correct for `uint32_t`. `%ld` takes a `long int`, `%hu` takes a `short unsigned int`.

Comment: @Melye77 You didn't provide a complete program.

Comment: It is the complete program. I've just commented everything else and this problem persists. My counter i won't change it's value. How does scanf/printf affect the value of a variable that I'm not even touching? It's just inside the for.

Comment: Usually, by an unintended overwrite.

Comment: Oh you mean that by reading the variables wrong, I might be accesing memory and altering i? Ok that makes sense. I'll try adding scanf("%" SCNd32, &x);

Comment: ..more likely by writing them wrong.  scanf is very good at that:(

Comment: I changed it and I have the same issues.

Comment: As others have suggested, please post a complete piece of code that we can compile and run that exhibits the problem.  Without that, there's not much we can do to help you.

Comment: I posted the complete code for my server and client. The problem is in the client as I have noticed, in the first for loop

Comment: @Melye77 That contains far too much irrelevant code. As I've said before, "*Provide a complete program that demonstrates the issue (and contains no unrelated code).*"

Comment: I cut all the irrelevant code now. It's just the verifiable serve rand client working, trying to pass numbers to eachother, failing on the client side for loop

Comment: No matter how many times I hit 'refresh', I still see short int format specifiers on int arguments.  If an int is uninitialized and then a short int is scanffed into its address, that still leaves half an int uninitialized.

Comment: Get rid of the '%hu'.  Eliminate, eradicate, extinguish, exterminate.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
  uint32_t len1; 

  ...

  scanf("%hu", &len1);
```

definitely provokes the infamous undefined behaviour. Anything could happen afterwards! Fix this to be

```
  scanf("%u", &len1);
```

---

Also this

```
  scanf("%" SCNd32,  &nr);
```

is still wrong as `nr` is unsigned.

It should be

```
  scanf("%" SCNu32,  &nr);
```

---

In the server this

```
  int l =sizeof(client_addr);
```

should be

```
  socklen_t l =sizeof(client_addr);
```